# How to send Web push notification to user after receiving endpoint id in database

Tags: javascript, php, web-services, push-notification

I have been reading few article about Web Push Notification API and found that Google gives push notification service for free via FCM.
I saw a google documentation how this can be done for Chrome, Now I already develop serviceworker.js file and insert endpoint into my database.
And now i want to send notification from admin panel to user. i have also used curl here is code
Please suggest i have to use serviceworker.js/manifest.json file again or can i do with only this code.

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AIzaSyBahgRuILBYJXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' );
$sql=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM subscribe_users where id= '17'");
$registrationIds=array();
while($row=$sql->fetch_assoc()){
    $registrationIds[] = $row['registration_id'];
}
$ids=json_encode($registrationIds);
//echo $ids;
$fields = array('registration_ids'  => $registrationIds);
//var_dump($fields);
$headers = array('Authorization: key='. API_ACCESS_KEY,'Content-Type: application/json');
//var_dump($headers);


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
```